# How can two positive dependent correlation coefficients differ significantly without differing significantly from zero?

Tags: correlation

I have  3 variables A, B and C, which are all markedly skewed. Below, I indicate correlations between two variables, e.g., A and B as $r_{ab}$.
Using the following test with with $n-2$ degrees of freedom

$$t= \frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{1-r^2}$$

- $r_{ac}$ is positive but not significantly different from zero,
- $r_{bc}$ is positive but not significantly different from zero, and
- $r_{ab}$ is significantly different from zero.

Then using [Williams t test](http://books.google.de/books?id=5WFohzuwzP0C&pg=PA381&lpg=PA381&dq=howell+williams+t+correlation&source=bl&ots=oRJeJ1RsdQ&sig=k0H8uDGDJbMhzUrsk_OKGUi5ufQ&hl=de&sa=X&ei=s1jwUZ7uD4rEswba54HoBA&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=williams&f=false)

- $r_{ac}$ and $r_{bc}$ are not significantly different from each other.

How can this be possible? 
**Shouldn't the difference between two positive correlations always be non-significant when they are both not significantly different from zero?**

Comment: There may be a typo because you seem to contradict yourself - are $r_{ac}$ and $r_{bc}$ significantly different from eachother or not?

Comment: @PeterEllis I've edited the question a bit to make it easier to read the key points. I've edited again in response to your comment. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us define the difference between two correlations with one shared variable $C$ as

$$\Delta r = r_{ac} - r_{bc}$$

The standard error of $\Delta r$ get smaller as the absolute value of the correlation between the non-shared variables $r_{ab}$ gets larger. However, the standard error of either of the component correlations $r_{ac}$ and $r_{bc}$ is unaffected by the absolute size of $r_{ab}$. Thus, at a certain absolute size of $r_{ab}$ the standard error of $\Delta r$ will be smaller than the standard error for either $r_{ac}$ or $r_{bc}$. In this sense **it is not surprising to get a significant difference between correlations despite the fact that neither of the two correlations are significantly different from zero as long as the correlation between common variables is reasonably large**.

**An R example:**
Here's a simple example where the individual correlations of .05 and .1 with a sample size of 100 would not be significantly different from zero, but where the correlation between the two shared variables is .97, the difference between the two correlations is significantly different.

```
library(psych)
paired.r(xy=.05, xz=.1, yz=.97, n=100)

Call: paired.r(xy = 0.05, xz = 0.1, yz = 0.97, n = 100)
[1] "test of difference between two correlated  correlations"
t = -2.06  With probability =  0.04
```